# Is the use of thread.yield() good practice in java at present?

Tags: java, multithreading, sleep, yield, thread-sleep

i was reading the book effective java (but second edition) and says that "Thread priorities are among the least portable features of the Java platform". And in blogs there are people that prefer sleep() over yield(), or says that yield() never must be used. But this is old information, is even valid those affirmations?

Comment: Yes, this is unlikely to change, as Java threads rely on underlying operating system threads.

Comment: It has never been good practice. `yield()` hasn't done anything useful in operating systems since the introduction of Windows 95, or in Java, except possibly in the short-lived 'green threads' versions.

Comment: @EJP  then, do you use sleep() instead yield() ?

Comment: Use them for what? I would use `sleep()` when I want to sleep, but I never want to do that. If you're asking about `Thread.sleep(0)`, it's pointless. The operating system is quite capable of scheduling threads without your assistance.

Comment: What is the problem which you want to solve with `yield()`?

Comment: @DraganBozanovic i process a large and heavy iteration in a loop inside the run method of my thread, i want relinquish the cpu and don't overload it. This can be done with yield, but i did read that sleep() is another option

Comment: The operating system takes care of it. Don't worry about it. You might consider lowering the thread priority.

Comment: ok, i'll check it, thanks

Comment: Yeah - if it's doing useful work, let it do it:)

Answer (score 2):

The answer is in the [Java 8 javadocs for yield](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#yield--):

> It is rarely appropriate to use this method. It may be useful for debugging or testing purposes, where it may help to reproduce bugs due to race conditions. It may also be useful when designing concurrency control constructs such as the ones in the java.util.concurrent.locks package.

Comment: Per many of the comments to the original question, as the docs indicate, you should ask why you want to yield, and in almost all cases there's a better option. Thread.sleep(0), or any real value when you have no actual reason to sleep, is just terrible. Using Thread.setPriority() is probably good enough for most cases. With multiple cores, it's OK for a thread to be busy.